# How to get values from nested json array using spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have this array

```
val myJson = {
"record": {
"recordId": 100,
"name": "xyz",
"version": "1.1",
"input": [
  {
    "format": "Database",
    "type": "Oracle",
    "connectionStringId": "212",
    "connectionString": "ksfksfklsdflk",
    "schemaName": "schema1",
    "databaseName": "db1",
    "tables": [
      {
        "table_name":"one"
      }
      {
        "table_name":"two"
      }
    ]
  }
]    
}
}
```

I am using this code to get this json in dataframe

```
val df = sparkSession.read.json(myjson)
```

I want values of schemaName & databaseName, how can i get them?

```
val schemaName = df.select("record.input.schemaName") //not working
```

Someone, please help me

Comment: You can't read json this way, you have to load it from file or create dataset. `val df = spark.read.json(Seq(myJson).toDS())`.  Your `"input"` is an array so you should pass required index, for example `df.select("record.input[0].schemaName")`

Comment: I am reading it from file only, sorry df.select("record.input[0].schemaName") --> this i already tried, doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explode the array column `record.input` then select the fields you want :

```
df.select(explode(col("record.input")).as("inputs"))
  .select("inputs.schemaName", "inputs.databaseName")
  .show

//+----------+------------+
//|schemaName|databaseName|
//+----------+------------+
//|   schema1|         db1|
//+----------+------------+
```